# XSL Approach without Modifying a Variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I was attempting to modify an XSL stylesheet that translates XML to a CSV format where the number of columns can vary and a new heading line is required when that occurs.

I wanted to store a variable with the current heading and compare to the previous heading and then output the current heading if the two didn't match.

This approach requires the previous heading variable to be updated for the next comparison and updating variables is not allowed in XSL. So I am looking for another approach.

Thanks

A simple output example for three records resulting in five lines of output, lines 2, 3 and 5 are data, lines 1 and 4 are header lines:

```
First,Last
John,Smith
Sally,Ford
First,Middle,Last
Frank,Anthony,Jones
```

For the input

```
<People>
  <Person>
    <Index>1</Index>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>First</Name>
      <Value>John</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Last</Name>
      <Value>Smith</Value>
    </Attribute>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Index>2</Index>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>First</Name>
      <Value>Sally</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Last</Name>
      <Value>Ford</Value>
    </Attribute>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Index>3</Index>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>First</Name>
      <Value>Frank</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Middle</Name>
      <Value>Anthony</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Last</Name>
      <Value>Jones</Value>
    </Attribute>
  </Person>
</People>
```

Comment: 1: Can you post your current XSLT attempt, or at least the relevant bits; 2: it seems like it would be better to just generate the maximum number of columns and have blanks/nulls where they're not needed, is there a reason you aren't doing that?

Comment: Would it be permissible to sort the records by their attribute set (so that each header appears only once)? If yes, can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: To Dan Field: I don't have anything meaningful to post for the XSLT. 

One XSLT hard codes a specific header at the top of the file which is used for legacy file transfer.

Another template puts the header entries inline (e.g. First=John, Last=Smith) and that file requires a secondary application to process to the desired format but is more flexible for current usage.

To Michael Hor: the output format is not changeable and sorting could cause issues in some circumstances.

Comment: Sample data is simplified, the number of possible attributes is large so a single common header is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, that works in XSLT 1.0.

It starts off by selecting only the first `Person` element. The template that matches (any) `Person` element has a parameter containing the previous headers (initially) empty, and then starts off by getting the header for the current row. 
If the current header is different to the previous, it can output it.

It then outputs the row itself, and then recursively calls the next `Person` element with the current headers now as the previous one

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/People">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Person[1]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Person">
        <xsl:param name="previous" />
        <xsl:variable name="current">
            <xsl:for-each select="Attribute">
                <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$current != $previous">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($current, '&#10;')" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="Attribute">
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Person[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="previous" select="$current" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0 though, you can use `xsl:for-each-group` to simplify this, and remove even the need for parameters

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/People">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Person" group-adjacent="string-join(Attribute/Name, ',')">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:value-of select="Attribute/Value" separator="," />
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```